# Unique number that is generate from a seed

Tags: c#, algorithm

I don't know whether this is correct place to ask this question.

I want to implement an authentication by giving my user a software with embeded hard coded number says it is x that is embeded in the software that the user won't know. The software has a button then when user press it, it will be able to generate random number**s** randomly such as a, b, c, d, e f.... etc based on x

When a user entering my website, they need to use the software that has x hard coded in it and generate a random number, says **c**. Entering username in my website and c as password (generated password on the fly using software), my website knows that the c is really generated by x (qualified) which is a secret code I implement in my software and distribute it to the user. So I allow the user to login. If the random number the user is entering does not generated based on x, I would immediately know and prevent user from login. The reason behind this implementation is to prevent fix password.

Conclusion, Is there an algorithm, that given x

```
f(x) = randomnumbers
g(x, randomnumbers) = true/false
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the [HMACSHA1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha1.aspx) class.

Given a private key, you can generate a secure digest of the username.

With that said, you need to be really careful about implementing "enhanced" security in your app.  The main issue I see is that the key doesn't expire and you have no way of revoking it.

You may be better off looking into client certificates or soft tokens if you want to kick it up a notch.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution might be to just store `x` in your own database when you generate it and insert it into your software. Then when the software wants to connect, it sends `x` and your site checks it's existence against your database. This is pretty much just a serial except that instead of checking the serial (your `x` value) against a pattern, you check it against actual, generated keys. No keygen can put a generated key into your database.

Worried about `x` being intercepted? Just make sure to use HTTPS. No MITM, no pass the hash, no user involvement (i.e. transparent).